# dynamically making threads in python for each user read in from text file

Tags: python, multithreading

So i have made a program that updates peoples boxs automatically, i had it all working then i went back and made it multithreaded, Everything works when i hard code the threads in my self, now i want to make a new thread for every user read in from the file, I have no idea how to do this for my program. The rest of my program is done just need to dynamically make threads. My code is below, i commented where i think the threads should start.

```
def run(self)
   try:
     location = "location"
     onloc = "onloc"
     port = 22
     self.Put(location, onloc, self.ThreadIP, self.ThreadPw, self.ThreadUser, port)
     re = self.HTTPing("https://%s"  %self.ThreadIP)
     while not re:
          time.sleep(60)
          self.HTTPing("https://%s"  %self.ThreadIP)
          print "Is on"
     except:
         print ("This ip does not est %s" %self.ThreadIP)


with open("People.txt" , 'r') as inFile:                        
   for line in inFile:
      ip,user,password = line.strip().split(',')
      ""what should i put here to make threads
```

Comment: `MyThreadClass(arguments,go,here).start()`?

Comment: You just need to create instances of your thread class, passing in the proper arguments.  You might want to store these instances inside of some kind of data structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert, but I did something like this for dynamic threading for a small project.  It took me about 4 hours to create, and since then haven't used it!

thread.py:

```
def threadcode():
    do_stuff = True
```

master.py:

```
from thread import threadcode as thread1
from thread import threadcode as thread2
from thread import threadcode as thread3
from thread import threadcode as thread4
# add more as required, or create dynamically
threadstostart = ['thread1','thread2','thread3','thread4']
# list of threads to start can be created dynamically as per the imports    

while True:
    #get missing threads
    threadsrunning = []
    for name in threading.enumerate():      #for each thread running
        threadname = str(name)              #convert thread object reference to string
        if "MainThread" in threadname:      #exclude main thread
            continue
        i = threadname.find("(") + 1        #extract thread name
        j = threadname.find(",")            #this will need to change if Python changes format
        threadname = threadname[i:j]        
        threadsrunning.append(threadname)   #add running thread to list

    threadsnotrunning = list(set(threadstostart) - set(threadsrunning)) #calculate list of threads not running

    for threadname in threadsnotrunning:
        threadtostart = globals()[threadname]                           # set missing thread
        thread = threading.Thread(name=threadname,target=threadtostart) # set threading object
        thread.start()                                                  # start thread

    sleep(10)  #do nothing for a bit
```

You can create the imports where you state

```
""what should i put here to make threads
```

and build up your "threadstostart" list, and immediately run the thread starter code I use above.  You'll still need to pass in your arguments to identify what each thread relates to...